# Firebase Child Listener Callback Returns one value and null for second value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm facing very strange results when working firebase realtime database for Android.
The main problem is:

1. When I try to add a child with two fields, the onChildAdded method returns the inserted value for first key and null for second and is not called for second value of the newly inserted child.
2. When I try to do the same thing with valueEventListener, the onDataChange method is called twice whenever a new child is created. In the first callback, the value of one field in returned and second value is null and in second callback both updated values are returned.

I have this structure in my firebase database.

```
{
  "users" : {
    "-LOOlXqtc0XK3ZXLKFc6" : {
      "Age" : 50,
      "Name" : "Ali"
    },
    "-LOPIfgGQMhyMkRMcpTb" : {
      "Age" : 80,
      "Name" : "New Name"
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my MainActivity code:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mRef = mDatabase.getReference("users");
```

This code is executed on Insert Data button's on click.

```
private void runCode(View view){
        String name = mInputText.getText().toString();
        int age= Integer.parseInt(mInputNum.getText().toString());

        String key = mRef.push().getKey();
        mRef.child(key).child("Name").setValue(name);
        mRef.child(key).child("Age").setValue(age);
}
```

And this is read data button's on click method using valueEventListener.

```
private void readData(View view) {
        //read data here 
        //this read data method has value listener not child listener
        mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Person data=  dataSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);
                Map<String,Object> data1= (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: Name: "+data1.get("Name"));
                Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: Age: "+data1.get("Age"));
                Log.d(TAG, "This is Person: "+data);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
}
```

The logcat output is this:
This is when I click on Read data method for the first time.

```
D/MyTag: onChildAdded: Name: Ali
D/MyTag: onChildAdded: Age: 50
D/MyTag: This is Person: Person{Name='Ali', Age=50}
```

And this is logcat output when I insert a new child with Name="New Name" and age=80.

```
D/MyTag: onChildAdded: Name: Ali
D/MyTag: onChildAdded: Age: 50
D/MyTag: This is Person: Person{Name='Ali', Age=50}
D/MyTag: onChildAdded: Name: New Name
D/MyTag: onChildAdded: Age: null
D/MyTag: This is Person: Person{Name='New Name', Age=0}
D/MyTag: onChildAdded: Name: Ali
D/MyTag: onChildAdded: Age: 50
D/MyTag: This is Person: Person{Name='Ali', Age=50}
D/MyTag: onChildAdded: Name: New Name
D/MyTag: onChildAdded: Age: 80
D/MyTag: This is Person: Person{Name='New Name', Age=80}
```

The callback method is separately for each field, it returns one field at a time, but this make sense that the setField is called twice so may be thats why it is called. But with child listener, the case is even worse.

Here is Read Code method with childListener implementation.

```
private void readData(View view) {
        //read data here
        mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Map<String,Object> data= (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                Person p=dataSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);

                Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: Name: "+data.get("Name"));
                Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: Age: "+data.get("Age"));

                Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: Person is: "+p);
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot       dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
}
```

Here is the logcat output when I click read data button for first time:

```
D/MyTag: onChildAdded: Name: Ali
D/MyTag: onChildAdded: Age: 50
D/MyTag: onChildAdded: Person is: Person{Name='Ali', Age=50}
D/MyTag: onChildAdded: Name: New Name
D/MyTag: onChildAdded: Age: 80
D/MyTag: onChildAdded: Person is: Person{Name='New Name', Age=80}
```

And this is the output with adding a new child with Name="Usman" and age=50

```
D/MyTag: onChildAdded: Name: Usman
D/MyTag: onChildAdded: Age: null
D/MyTag: onChildAdded: Person is: Person{Name='Usman', Age=0}
```

Only this happens in callback. The age is not returned but value is stored in Database correctly.

Please help. I have only one listener attached and always run the app after stopping running process.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run this code:

```
mRef.child(key).child("Name").setValue(name);
mRef.child(key).child("Age").setValue(age);
```

Each call to `setValue` gets sent to the Firebase database separately. So you're performing two independent write operations to the database. And each write operation may be sent out to the listeners.

To make them go out as one write operation, combine the two properties into a single call to `setValue()`:

```
Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("Name", name);
map.put("Age", age);
mRef.child(key).setValue(values);
```

This will perform a single write to the database, with the same final result. But it will only trigger the listener once.

#### Update

If we look back at your initial code:

```
mRef.child(key).child("Name").setValue(name);
mRef.child(key).child("Age").setValue(age);
```

The first call to setValue causes `$key` to be created, while the second call merely updates the `Age` node under it. When using a child listener on `mRef`, that means that the first call to `setValue()` triggers `onChildAdded`, while the second call triggers `onChildChanged()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know calling setvalue twice triggers two seperate API calls. But even then the call back method should return age value. Why it is returning null

Comment: The second `setValue` triggers `onChildChanged`. I added an explanation of that to my answer. The solution is the same: use a single call to `setValue()`.

Comment: Thanks. You are right! I figured this out today but never got the time to update the question. One thing more, if I save a POJO object in database, can it be retrieved as map or it has to be retrieved as POJO.

Comment: In the database it is just saved as JSON, so you can always retrieve it as a `Map`. The other way around depends: you can only read as a POJO if the JSON matches the properties of the POJO.